# angularjs not sequentially executing

Tags: angularjs

my  angularjs code is as follows:

```
     holidays = new Array();
     var deferred = $q.defer();
        servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Dcrs/activityDay.php',{
            "date":d
        }).then(function(result) {

            $scope.holidays = result; 

        alert(holidays.length);
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });
        return deferred;


     alert("holiday length after service post"+holidays.length);
```

angularjs is not sequential as it occurs to me. so this code executes in the end! this code of mine is inserted in such an order in my angularjs controller that the code down below depends on this 'holidays' array. what happens in my above code is the alert 'holiday length after service post0' pops up first and than after service post executes in the end, the length of the array is actually displayed.

now i tried using $q,promises,deffered as above but it doesn't seem to work.i have injected $q only in my angularjs controller.
 is there anything wrong i have done in the above code? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A promise returns another promise, so you can use this 2nd promise to have your logic performed in the order you wish.  You are also complicating things in this situation with the $q service.

```
holidays = new Array();

var promise = servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Dcrs/activityDay.php',{
    "date":d
}).then(function(result) {
    $scope.holidays = result; 
    alert(holidays.length);
    return result;
});

promise.then(function(result) {
    alert("holiday length after service post"+holidays.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is executed sequentially, it's just that the request takes time to resolve, but it starts before the alert. You should handle the request first, then alert the result inside the "then".

Comment: thats exactly what i don't want to happen. i want to wait till the request is resolved and than the code down below should execute......so what should i do now? i already tried $q (or have i done a wrong implementation of $q,promises syntax wise -im confused where to put that return)

Comment: just remove the last alert, as it will be executed at the same time as the request, and put it after the resolve

Comment: you can use $http instead of $q.defer() as well...

$http.post(url, data).then(response) {
  $scope.holidays = response.data;
  console.log($scope.holidays);
}